# Python : python-crontab does not execute

Tags: python, flask, package, cron

I want to make crontab execute python script every minute, but It seems like crontab does not execute script at all.

This is python file where I made crontab job.

schedule.py

```
from crontab import CronTab


def main():
    my_cron = CronTab(user='jelly')
    cmd = '.venv/bin/python Users/jelly/PycharmProjects/test/writeDate.py'
    job = my_cron.new(cmd, comment='test')
    job.minute.every(1)

    my_cron.write()
    print(my_cron.render())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is message when I run schdule.py

```
* * * * * .venv/bin/python Users/hyun/PycharmProjects/test/writeDate.py # test
```

This is script supposed to be executed

```
import datetime

with open('dateInfo.txt', 'a') as outFile:
    outFile.write('\n' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

When I go into terminal and typed command line

```
ps aux | grep cron
```

I could see messages like this

```
root             47903   0.0  0.0  2460724   1696   ??  Ss    6:28PM   0:00.31 /usr/sbin/cron
jelly             71389   0.0  0.0  2432804   1380 s003  R+   12:00PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn cron
```

This message sometimes shows R+ and sometimes shoes S+, so I assumed that crontab is running, but I can't find any new txt files that supposed to be created in directory. I wonder which part went wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: Try using sudo when running the file could be something as simple as a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in path to python. Cron runs with limited environment, so it does not know where is *.venv/bin/python* and *Users/jelly/PycharmProjects/test/writeDate.py*
You must use [absoulte paths](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)